# Linux shell script - String trimming for dash

Tags: linux, shell

I am attempting to get the mac address from my Raspberry Pi take the last 6 characters of the mac to use as the hostname alongside a fixed string.

here is what I'v managed to get working from other sources so far, but I am now totally stuck trying to trim the string down.

```
#!/bin/sh -e

MAC="$( sed "s/^.*macaddr=\([0-9A-F:]*\) .*$/\1/;s/://g" /proc/cmdline )"

MAC1="${MAC??????%}"

echo "$MAC1"
```

the shell being used by the Pi appears to be Dash, so the usual BASH commands that would have this done in no-time don't want to work or seem to generate errors when run within the script.

The full script that I am using in rc.local is below.

any advice on a way to-do this would be greatly received.

```
MAC="pi""$( sed "s/^.*macaddr=\([0-9A-F:]*\) .*$/\1/;s/://g" /proc/cmdline )"
echo "$MAC" > "/etc/hostname"
CURRENT_HOSTNAME=$(cat /proc/sys/kernel/hostname)
sed -i "s/127.0.1.1.*$CURRENT_HOSTNAME/127.0.1.1\t$MAC/g" /etc/hosts
hostname $MAC
```

Comment: can you provide some sample of your `/proc/cmdline` output as well as your desired output based on that?

Comment: @fedorqui dma.dmachans=0x7f35 bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=1920 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=1080 bcm2709.boardrev=0xa02082 bcm2709.serial=0x85f8e90b smsc95xx.macaddr=B8:27:EB:F8:E9:0B bcm2708_fb.fbswap=1 bcm2709.uart_clock=48000000 sdhci-bcm2708.emmc_clock_freq=250000000 vc_mem.mem_base=0x3dc00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x3f000000  dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait

Comment: Please [edit] your question rather than using the comments to add detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the `cut` command on your Pi, you could
do

```
MAC1=$( echo $MAC | cut -c 7-12 )
```

Comment: So my scripting might not be the prettiest or the quickest but it does exactly what I need it to-do now, thanks for the answer Dmitri.

for anyone that wants to-do the same on a raspberry pi you can modify `/etc/rc.local` and add the following code 

`MAC="$( sed "s/^.*macaddr=\([0-9A-F:]*\) .*$/\1/;s/://g" /proc/cmdline )"
MAC1="Pi"$( echo $MAC | cut -c 7-12 )
echo "$MAC1" > "/etc/hostname"

CURRENT_HOSTNAME=$(cat /proc/sys/kernel/hostname)
sed -i "s/127.0.1.1.*$CURRENT_HOSTNAME/127.0.1.1\t$MAC1/g" /etc/hosts
hostname $MAC1`

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using sed to process the string, I'd suggest adding another command:

```
MAC=$(sed -e 's/^.*macaddr=\([0-9A-F:]*\) .*$/\1/' \
          -e 's/://g' \
          -e 's/.*\(.\{6\}\)/\1/' /proc/cmdline)
```

The extra sed command extracts the last 6 characters from each line (I assume that you only have one?). You can combine the commands into a single string if you prefer, though I find this approach to be more readable.

Comment: this works but it removes the last characters which are the unique ones of the MAC in this case which are the ones I am interested in..

Comment: @mklement0 thanks for mentioning that, I was in the process of suggesting that the OP used sed anyway, so I've removed the "bashism".